# Какие ранее нерешаемые задачи решает Content Security Policy?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xss, csp

Если мы говорим о XSS, то неужели недостаточно простой функции `htmlspecialchars`?

Просто мне не совсем понятна логика авторов CSP, если вас конкретно взломали, получив доступ к редактированию страниц - то что тогда мешает хакеру удалить все ваши замечательные CSP заголовки/теги?

Даже если не лениться применять CSP -  фильтровать специальные HTML символы всё равно придётся чтобы пользователь сам ничего не разломал. В итоге вообще не понятно зачем это CSP нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так давайте ещё раз расмотрим основное описание `CSP`

> Content Security Policy (CSP, политика защиты контента) — это механизм
>   обеспечения безопасности, с помощью которого можно защищаться от атак
>   с внедрением контента, например, межсайтового скриптинга (XSS, cross
>   site scripting). `CSP` описывает безопасные источники загрузки ресурсов,
>   устанавливает правила использования встроенных стилей, скриптов, а
>   также динамической оценки JavaScript — например, с помощью eval.
>   Загрузка с ресурсов, не входящих в «белый список», блокируется.

Если ваш хостинг взломали, получили полный доступ к файлам  - это уже беда, и многие защитные действия уже бесполезны, в плане `CSP`, и особенно если "вредитель" знает или замечает что на сайте настроена `CSP`, он конечно может спокойно удалить заголовки, однако часто бывает (как практика показывает) что после взлома "вредитель" просто вставляет свой код в файлы и уходит "восвояси".
Второй очень важный момент желательной настройки `CSP` это то что данные правила очень помогают при "незаконном" внедрении  `JS`, `IFRAME` и т.д  посредством браузера пользователя.

> Как отсутствие настроек CSP может навредить сайту?

Представьте что на ваш сайт заходят посетители, у который заражён вирусами браузер, и что происходит? посетитель видит (например) рекламные баннеры, ссылки, айфреймы и т.д ,  не думаю что кому то хочется чтобы посетители видели чужую рекламу на своём сайте или переходили бы по чужим ссылкам.
Конечно в интернете пока бытует мнение, что:

> Новый веб-стандарт страдает от существенных недостатков, ставящих под
>   сомнение его пригодность как защиты от XSS

однако есть намного больше причин для поддержки и использования данного стандарта.В настояшее время пока есть недостатки данной политики, многие браузеры бывают 'неадекватны', однако я думаю в ближайщее время данные недочёты уберут и интернет станет более безопастным! )

Comment: Ответ признаю лучшим, но CSP всё равно ерунда.

Comment: Если смотреть на этот вопрос глобально - да, но есть все возможности для улучшения данного веб стандарта, возможно в ближайшем будущем, после CSP Level 3  они (разработчики) добьются многого ))